# Add / remove class after X amount of seconds

Tags: jquery, wordpress, carousel

I currently have a small function that adds / removes a class in 2 places when clicking a navigation bullet (it adds / removes the .active from the bullet itself and from a matching div with some info).

Is it possible to combine this with an automatic add / remove of the .active class (in both places) every, let's say, 10 seconds?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.case-1').addClass('active');
    $('#case-1').addClass('active');

$("#carousel-nav ul li").click(function() {
    $('#carousel-nav ul li.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

var divClass = $(this).attr('id')
    $('div').removeClass('active');
    $('.' + divClass).addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** First time misunderstood the question so here's another shot:

**Updated** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zainabr1/qy1t1h8h/1/)

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
   // toggle the class every 
   $('div').toggleClass('blue');  
   setTimeout(function(){
     // toggle another class
     $('div').toggleClass('red');  
   },2000)

},2000);
```

```css
.blue{
  color: blue;
}
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
testing 123
</div>
```

---

Wrap it in a:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   //actions to perform
}, 3000);
```

Replace *3000* with the time you want

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zainabr1/qy1t1h8h/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, but this isn't quite what I am looking for. I'm looking for (for example) case-1 has .active by default. After 3 seconds the .active gets removed from case-1 and added to case-2. Then after another 3 seconds the .active gets removed from case-2 and added to case-3. It should also loop, reset itself after the last cas-.

Comment: @imrafaelhi sorry misunderstood your question, I will work on it and change

Answer (score 0):

you can try calling a function to toggle your classes recursively

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num = 0;
    var cases = [to the max number of cases]
    var activateToggling = function(cases) {
       num=num+1;
       $('.case-'+(num-1)).toggleClass('active');
       $('#case-'+(num-1)).toggleClass('active');
       $('.case-'+num).toggleClass('active');
       $('#case-'+num).toggleClass('active');
       if(num==cases){
            num=1;
       }  
       setTimeout(activateToggling(cases), 3000);
    }
})
```